# Windows explorer - preview thumbnail of MOBI and AZW files

Tags: ebook-readers

I am able to preview epub thumbnail on windows explorer via CBX Shell. However, MOBI and AZW files didn't have a thumbnail. How to solve the problem? Should I convert to epub files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows machine, [MobiHandler](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=128030) should work for you.

Comment: Excuse me, do you have mobihandler file? The download link is dead.

Comment: Use the second [Skydrive link](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=88858BC052AEA782%21163&cid=88858BC052AEA782) and download mobihandler-1-0-setup.msi.

Comment: I installed mobihandler 1.1 on win10 but it doesn't work. I decided to delete mobi and azw and store ebooks only with pdf and epub formats.

Answer (score 0):

Works for ePub. Me and the developer created this

```
https://github.com/dark-knight404/DarkThumbs
```

Works for Mobi (Same as 4665 posted but this is the current link)

```
https://mega.nz/file/xhp02QLC#DQire5gBC1dD7KcVyQ-i47biNqvfBpgNqmv_T5tFmII
```

I am trying to work with DK101 to have DarkThumbs support Mobi and Azw, but coding costs money and takes time so I am trying to round up some donations to have it done.